# Comparing Dates with SQLAlchemy, SQLite

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am writing an application that uses SQLAlchemy with an SQLite database.  I believe my database, tables, and mapping are configured correctly because other operations work as expected.  I am trying to write a function that retrieves all objects whose date field matches a datetime.date() supplied as a parameter to the function.  Here is my first try:

```
def get_objects_matching_date(session,my_date):  
    return session.query(Table).filter(Table.date_field == my_date).all()
```

Event though I know that `Table` contains objects matching the criteria, the function returns nothing.

I know from reading the [SA documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/dialects/sqlite.html?highlight=sqlite#sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite) that sqlite has no native support for `date` or `datetime` types and that they are stored as strings.  But SA is supposed to handle the conversion to (when returning results) and from (when inserting records) `date` or `datetime` objects.  I assume that it should be able to handle this when running a comparison filter as well.  I've read several different SO threads and have considered using `between()` to filter out the objects matching `my_date`, but that doesn't seem like it should be necessary when an exact `==` is what I am looking for.   I've also looked into using `.filter(cast(Table.date_field,DATE) == my_date)` to ensure that I am getting a comparison of objects, but that did not seem to work either.

Clearly I am missing something about the way that SQLAlchemy handles dates, especially with SQLite databases. How can I get an exact match between a `Date` stored in the SQLite db by SQLAlchemy and the `datetime.date()` object supplied as a parameter? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above answers worked for me, but I found a solution via this link: https://gist.github.com/danielthiel/8374607

Use sqlachemy's `func.DATE()` function as follows:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func

session.query(Table).filter(func.DATE(Table.date_field) == my_date).all()
```

Comment: I can confirm this has worked wonders! Also works on SQLAlchemy 1.4

Answer (score 3):

This might be very late, but it better late than never, so it might benefit others :)

Try casting them both to Date:

```
from sqlalchemy import Date, cast
from datetime import datetime

created_at = datetime.now().date()
query.filter(cast(Model.created_at, Date) == cast(created_at,Date))
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: Sqlite doesn't support cast to date, it returns only year instead. This may return in incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem did indeed lie with conversion between strings (the representation of `Date` objects in SQLite) and `date` objects in python.  The solution below seems to work just fine, despite following a rather long sequence of conversions between datatypes (date->datetime->string).  Maybe there is another way, but this works.

```
def get_objects_matching_date(session,my_date):  
    return session.query(Table).\
        filter((strftime("%Y-%m-%d",datetime.combine(my_date,time()).timetuple())).all()
```